# Finite measure on the smallest ring

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $E$ be any nonempty class of sets and let $R(E)$ be the smallest ring generated by $E$. Let $\mu$ be a measure on $R(E)$ such that $\mu(A)<\infty$ for all $A\in E$. Then prove the $\mu(B)<\infty$ for all $B\in R(E)$.

Definition of ring:

A ring of sets is a nonempty class of sets $R$ such that

$E,F\in R$ implies that (1) $E\setminus F\in R$ and (2) $E\cup F\in R$.

To establish that I have tried to build a ring on which $\mu$ is finite. This essentially proves the claim. My first try is to consider the finite unions of the members of $E$. While this collection satisfies (2), I do not how to verify (1) . Is there any other way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\{B \in R(E): \mu(B) <\infty\}$ is a ring which contains $E$. Hence, $R(E) \subseteq \{B \in R(E): \mu(B) <\infty\}$ which proves the result.

Comment: Thank you @kaviramamurthy. However, $\{B\in R(E): \mu(A)< \infty\}$, I do not get the definition.

Comment: @pmun Sorry about the typo.

Comment: Now I get it, Thankyou @Kaviramamurthy